# Table matlab dynamic texts

Tags: matlab

I want to build a dynamic [table](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) in Matlab that creates new rows given a fixed number of column depending on how many times I perform some computations, saving the results and all the parameters that I use.
I'm having trouble here because if I try to write something like

```
Modes(indx,1) = {'function'num2char(n) num2char(m)};
```

inside a `for` to increase the index `indx` every time `n` changes in order to have

```
function1
function2
...
```

I get the error

> Error: Invalid expression. Check for missing multiplication operator, missing or unbalanced delimiters, or other syntax error. To
>   construct matrices, use brackets instead of parentheses.

I'm trying this way to avoid to use `sprintf` in order to have a cleaner and readable code.

The idea of table that I have is something like

```
Modes          n   m   r
function11     1   1   0.02
function12     1   2   5
...            ..  ..  ..
```

and then sort the entire table for `r` but first I need to put the two indexes that I need inside `Modes` cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you don't have a space between the end of `'functon'` and the first `num2char` call.

You should also use square brackets when concatenating a string. Note that I used num2str below, my version doesn't have a num2char function.

```
Modes(indx,1) = {['function' num2str(n) num2str(m)]}
```